# NodeJs base64 string incorrect

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, base64

I'm trying to encode an mp3 file to base64. I'm reading file line by line using `createInterface` and then concatenate the strings.

I then base64 encode the string using `new Buffer(str).string('base64')`

The encoded base64 is incorrect with + signs at every line read (assumption)

PHP base64 is working fine.

**The Node generated base64**
SUQzAwAAAAZVbFRJVDIAAABOAAAATG92ZSBZb3UgVG9uaWdodCBmdC4gS2FiemEgRGUgU21hbGwsIERKIE1hcGhvcmlzYSAmIFNoYXNoYSB8IHd3dy5iZWF0emphbS5jb21UUEUxAAAAIwAAAFtCZWF0ekphbV1NRlIgU291bHMgfCBiZWF0emphbS5jb21UQUxCAAAAEQAAAHd3dy5iZWF0emphbS5jb21UWUVSAAAABQAAADIwMTlUQ09OAAAADgAAAFBlcmZlY3QgTXVzaWNDT01NAAAAJQAAAGVuZwBEb3dubG9hZGVkIEZyb20gd3d3LmJlYXR6amFtLmNvbUFQSUMAAXTvv70AAABpbWFnZS9qcGVnAABEb3dubG9hZGVkIEZyb20gd3d3LmJlYXR6amFtLmNvbQDvv73vv73vv73vv70AEEpGSUYAAQEAAAEAAQAA77+977+9AO+

**PHP base64**

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

**Here is a sample code**

```
var interface = readline.createInterface({
input: fs.createReadStream(file)
}),
str = '';

interface.on('line', (line)=>{
    str += line;
} )

interface.on('close',()=>{
var base =  new Buffer.from(str).toString('base64');
res.send(  `<audio autoplay controls><source src="data:audio/mp3;base64,${base}"></source></audio>` )
   
})
```

Answer (score 2):

perhaps use `Buffer.from(str).toString('base64')`

Comment: No luck. It seems node is placing some characters at every  line end

Answer (score 0):

The combination of `readLine.createInterface` and  `fs.createReadStream` doesn't make much sense, as `createReadStream` already fires events like `data`, `error` and `end`.

The problem is also that you read by `line`, but that's not how you could read a binary file. How would you define a line in a binary (here .mp3) file? The code seems to read chunks of data of different size (whatever it considers a line), and appends a string. Probably the byte that is interpreted as line end gets lost.

And lastly, you would also get in trouble when the files is very large, because you add everything to a string and then create a buffer from it and output it at once. So it would require more than 3 times the size of your mp3 file in memory.

The solution below only uses `fs.createReadStream` and limits the size of a chunk to 60.000 bytes by setting the `{highWaterMark : 60000}`.

Note: the default size is 65536, but that would not work for the following base64 encoding. The data size must be a [multiple of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294511/questions-about-base64-encoding/59295365#59295365)!

The received `data` is a `buffer`, which can be converted to `base64`directly.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
var file = "test.mp3";

let stream = fs.createReadStream(file, {highWaterMark : 60000});

stream.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log("data length " + data.length)
    var base = data.toString('base64');
    fs.appendFile('test.b64', base, function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("wrote " + base.length + " bytes");
      })  

}).on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
}).on('end', () => {
    console.log("success");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with: `const encoded = Buffer.from(stringValue, 'base64').toString();`

Or `atob()` and `btoa()` functions (on client side).
Here is the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob).